# How to get popular post from across a network?

Tags: plugins, multisite, popular-posts, widgets

I have a multisite network on WP 3.3.1. I now need to get all popular posts from across this network (preferably based on the amount of views).

Is this possible, and how do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simple list all last post about the network, not the popular posts; for popular posts you must use an plugin or track via Google Analytics etc.

```
<ul class='postlist no-mp'>

<?php 
$blogs = $wpdb->get_results( 
    "SELECT blog_id,path FROM {$wpdb->blogs} 
    WHERE blog_id != {$wpdb->blogid} 
    AND site_id = '{$wpdb->siteid}' 
    AND spam = '0' 
    AND deleted = '0' 
    AND archived = '0' 
    order by blog_id", ARRAY_A
); 
if ( 0 < count( $blogs ) ) :
    foreach( $blogs as $blog ) : 
        switch_to_blog( $blog[ 'blog_id' ] );

        if ( get_theme_mod( 'show_in_home', 'on' ) !== 'on' ) {
            continue;
        }

        $description  = get_bloginfo( 'description' );
        $blog_details = get_blog_details( $blog[ 'blog_id' ] );
        ?>
        <li class="no-mp">

            <h2 class="no-mp blog_title">
                <a href="<?php echo $blog_details->path ?>">
                    <?php echo  $blog_details->blogname; ?>
                </a>
            </h2>

            <div class="blog_description">
                <?php echo $description; ?>
            </div>

            <?php 
            query_posts( 'showposts=5' );
            if ( have_posts() ) :
                while( have_posts() ) :
                    the_post();
                    ?>
                    <div class="blog_post">
                        <div class="post_title">
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="post_excerpt">
                            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php endif; 
            restore_current_blog();
            ?>
        </li>
<?php endforeach;?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your code!
I only don´t understand why I would list all post instead of the popular ones?

Comment: but it is important, that you write, how you find the popular posts; its not an WP feature; it give different solutions via plugin or tracking tools and the result of this must you use in this example of code

Comment: ok I understand it now. I just don´t know how to do this ;o)
So if anybody can help (me) with this ...

Comment: Ok, so if I understand you correctly. Ican use a plugin like postviews to find the populair posts in a blog, and use those results in your code example?

Comment: Yes, right. Also Google Analytics or any statistic tool

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the techniques described here: http://www.artiss.co.uk/2011/07/using-google-analytics-data-to-show-popular-posts

It basically uses the functions provided by the Google Analytics Dashboard plugin to show the most popular post in your theme.